# Create header and footer on save event. Check if header or footer exists

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I created a macro-template (workbook.xltm) and moved it to `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`. So this file is opened as the default workbook.
The workbook contains a little script that is executed, when the user clicks on the save button. The script adds header and footer to all sheets.

My problem is the workflow as when a new file is opened, the user tends to alter the header by changing the company name for instance. Unfortunately at this point the file is not saved yet and so by hitting the save button, the header will be overwritten by the default company name from the script.

1. It would be nice to have a condition that checks if a header and footer already exists. That would be the point when the user saves the file for the first time. This would avoid the case in which the header is overwritten by the default header text of the script.
2. In addition to that it would be nice if the header and footer of the first sheet (from left) would be used for (copied to) all newly created sheets (if the user creates them). For now if a user creates a new sheet and hits the save button, the header/footer in the new sheet looks like the default header/footer from the script.

The script:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "Company: Company Ltd." & Chr(10) & "Cutoff date: 31.12.20XX"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "Filename: &F" & Chr(10) & "Sheet: &A"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(3.91)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.91)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input and support. I managed to create a template-file with a sheet called "Template", that already has nearly all required information that are used for all sheets that are created by the user. I now need to re-add the Workbook_BeforeSave event, because my current script can not handle the event where the user copies a sheet from another workbook to this sheet. So the copied sheet is missing header and footer.

The current script that adds header and footer to all newly created sheets:

It copies the information of the sheet "Template" to newly created sheets. So the "Template" sheet is a requirement.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Template").PageSetup
        strHeadLeft = .LeftHeader
        strHeadCenter = .CenterHeader
        strHeadRight = .RightHeader
        'strFootLeft = .LeftFooter
        'strFootCenter = .CenterFooter
        'strFootRight = .RightFooter
        bGotHeaders = True
    End With
    If bGotHeaders Then
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = strHeadLeft
            .CenterHeader = strHeadCenter

            If IsEmpty(strHeadRight) Then
                strHeadRight = _
                 "&10Ref: &B&10&KFF0000 XXX-XXX" & _
                  Chr(10) & _
                  "&B&K000000File date created: " & _
                  Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & Time & Chr(10) & _
                  "User: &B" & Application.UserName
            Else
                strHeadRight = strHeadRight & _
                 Chr(10) & _
                 "&B&K000000File date created: " & _
                 Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & Time & Chr(10) & _
                 "User: &B" & Application.UserName
            End If

            .RightHeader = strHeadRight
            .LeftFooter = "&10Filename: &F" & Chr(10) & "Sheet: &A"
            '.CenterFooter = strFootCenter
            .RightFooter = _
              "&10Page &P of &N"
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet Template does not exist." & vbCrLf & _
        "For this reason, the header and footer cannot be inserted into newly created spreadsheets.", _
        vbExclamation, "No Headers In Memory"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the left, center and right header of the default template simply empty, and check it upon save. Then I would save the values and copy them to all other sheets. If you have many sheets, it is worth turning print communication off temporarily.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ShActive as Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim sLH as String, sCH as String, sRH As String

    Application.Printcommunication = False
    Set shActive = ActiveSheet
    With Activesheet.PageSetup
         sLH = .LeftHeader
         sCH = .CenterHeader
         ...
         If lenb(sLH) = 0 And lenb(sCH) = 0 And lenb(sRH) = 0 Then ' all empty = set defaults
              sLH = "Company: Company Ltd." & Chr(10) & "Cutoff date: 31.12.20XX"
              ....
         End If
    End With

    For Each sh in ActiveWorkBook.Sheets
        With sh.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = sLH
            ...
        End With
    Next
    shActive.Activate ' just for sure
    Application.Printcommunication = True
```

Comment: `I would leave the .. header of the default template simply empty, and check it upon save.` This won't work as I need to save the template when I created it and so the script fires to fill the template. I noticed a bug in your script: I open the template that has one default sheet. I change Company Ltd. to Else Ltd.. I save and close it. I open the saved file and add a sheet. Save it. You will notice that the company changed to its default value.

Comment: Adding sheet fires the Workbook_NewSheet event,. You could use it to prefill header and footer.